# Need help writing a Sql query with multiple tables and a count

Tags: sql

There is 3 Tables

1. ITEM

-itemID

2.INVENTORY

-quantity

3.CHARACTERS

-charID

ITEM 1---many INVENTORY 8----1 CHARACTER

I want to find the top 10 most stacked items that is stacked in the characters inventory. So in the end it will be something like itemID 1 has 4 stacks and itemID 2 has 3 stacks. In a table.

This is where I am currently at after trying to do this for a while

```
SELECT TOP 10 COUNT(INVENTORY.itemID) as Stacks, ITEM.itemID
FROM INVENTORY
JOIN ITEM
ON INVENTORY.itemID = ITEM.itemID
WHERE INVENTORY.quantity>1
```

I am getting a aggregate error and I dont know how to fix this query

```
Column 'ITEM.itemID' is invalid in the select list because it is not  
contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

Any help is welcome Thanks :)

Comment: You need to add `GROUP BY ITEM.itemID` at the end.

Comment: I just lost half my brain from the facepalm thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `GROUP BY` to count each itemID.

```
SELECT TOP 10 COUNT(INVENTORY.itemID) as Stacks, ITEM.itemID
FROM INVENTORY
JOIN ITEM
ON INVENTORY.itemID = ITEM.itemID
WHERE INVENTORY.quantity>1
GROUP BY ITEM.itemID
```

Since you do `TOP 10` I also suggest adding `ORDER BY` at the end:

```
ORDER BY Stacks desc
```